# Convert nan to Zero when numpy dtype is "object"

Tags: python, numpy, nan, dtype

I have a numpy array that contains nan. I attempted to convert those nans to zeros using

```
 X_ = np.nan_to_num(X_, copy = False)
```

but it didn't work. I suspect its because dtype of X_ is object. I attempted to convert that to float64 using

```
X_= X_.astype(np.float64)
```

but that didn't work either

Is there a way to convert nan to zero when dtype is object?

Comment: what's your `X_`  type and dtype?

Comment: @Alpha dtype is 'object' and type is a 'numpy.ndarray'

Comment: how do you get this 'object' nan?

Comment: @Alpha I matched the words in a list with keys in a dictionary containg key- value pairs, then loaded the corresponding values into a list and converted the list to an array. the dtype of the array became 'object' and the instances where a word and a key didnt match, i filled with a zero array but instead when i inspect i saw nan.   vector_values.append(self._E.get(w, Q) where w is the key of the dictionary and Q is a numpy zero array.

Comment: from your comments, I think there is something not proper. maybe you should directly post your question that why your expected zero becomes nan

Comment: @Alpha Ok thanks. I've done that here [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57851237/filled-with-numpy-zero-but-getting-nan-instead)

Comment: Don't just say "it didn't work"; show the error.   OK the first might raise an error, just not making a change.  But what about the second?  Why couldn't it be converted to float?  What element prevented it.

Comment: @hpaulj the second raised a ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence which was pointing to that particular line of code. I havent been able to interpret what exactly that means.

Comment: You will need to examine the `X_` array in some detail.  `sequence` means something with several items, like a list or array.  Apparently your array is not a simple array of numbers, 0s and `np.nan`.

Comment: @hpaulj yes, it does contain several arrays. X_ is meant to be a (3663, 200) array with each element containing  a 1*200 vector. Would that be the problem and how can i fix it?

Comment: I'm confused.  Do you mean a (3663,200) numeric array, or a (3663,200) object array containing arrays.  What is the actual shape?  (3663,)?  If it is 1d with object dtype, then probably the elements are a mix of arrays of different shape, or arrays and non-array objects.  I don't think you can fix this after the fact - you need to get the initial construction right.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199217/discussion-between-kosi-and-hpaulj).

Answer (score 0):

```
a  = [np.nan]
b = np.array(a)
c = np.nan_to_num(b)
print(b)
print(c)
```

result:

```
[nan]
[0.]
```

it works. check you X_ format.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that because of the object type, a conversion to float does not work. Might be a bit hacky, but you could try to convert to str:

```
X_.astype(str).replace('np.NaN', 0).astype(float)
```

Comment: i did that with this :   X_ = X_.astype(str).replace('nan', np.zeros((1, 200))).astype(float) and it gives    ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Comment: What I tried to do is replace each np.nan element with a 0. You are trying to replace each np.nan element with a full array (`np.zeros((1, 200))`). That's why it does not work. Just use the replace with 0.

Comment: Unfortunately, i can't replace with just one 0, as all the arrays need to be the same shape and the other entries are already (1,200). Is there another work around i can explore?

Comment: You are supposed to replace each of the 200 elements with a 0 (if np.nan). You are trying to replace each element with a 200 element vector each (making it a 200x200 matrix).

Comment: X_ contains 3663 rows and 200 columns, some of the rows are just nan, that why i want to replace each nan with a (1, 200) array. In my case, nan isnt an element, its a whole array.  Also, i got the same error when is used a single zero instread of a zero array

Answer (score 0):

If your array contains only "reasonable" (see below) elements then you can use the following work around:

```
np.where(X_==X_,X_,0)
```

By reasonable I mean that an element e satisfies e==e with the sole exception of nan. This should for example be the case if no userdefined classes are used as elements.

Comment: from my understanding, np.where is used when you want to find the location of particular entries in an array, which isn't what im trying to do. My heading might have been a bit confusing but i want to convert all the nan to a numpy.zero array.

Comment: @Kosi Read the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).

Answer (score 0):

The "object" dtype was causing me a problem too. But your `astype(np.float64)` actually did work for me. Thanks!

```
print("Creating a numpy array from a mixed type DataFrame can create an 'object' numpy array dtype:")
A = np.array([1., 2., 3., np.nan]); print('A:', A, A.dtype)
B = pd.DataFrame([[1., 2., 3., np.nan,],  [1, 2, 3, '4']]
                  ).to_numpy();  print('B:', B, B.dtype, '\n')

print('Converting vanilla A is fine:\n', np.nan_to_num(A, nan=-99), '\n')
print('But not B:\n', np.nan_to_num(B, nan=-99), '\n')
print('Not even this slice of B, \nB[0, :] : ', B[0, :])
print(np.nan_to_num(B[0, :], nan=-99), '\n')

print('The astype(np.float64) does the trick here:\n', 
      np.nan_to_num(B[0, :].astype(np.float64), nan=-99), '\n\n')
```

Output:

```
Creating a numpy array from a mixed type DataFrame can create an 'object' numpy array dtype:
A: [ 1.  2.  3. nan] float64
B: [[1.0 2.0 3.0 nan]
 [1.0 2.0 3.0 '4']] object 

Converting vanilla A is fine:
 [  1.   2.   3. -99.] 

But not B:
 [[1.0 2.0 3.0 nan]
 [1.0 2.0 3.0 '4']] 

Not even this slice of B, 
B[0, :] :  [1.0 2.0 3.0 nan]
[1.0 2.0 3.0 nan] 

The astype(np.float64) does the trick here:
 [  1.   2.   3. -99.]
```