# Filled with numpy.zero but getting nan instead

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, dictionary

I have a Class that contains various methods with include the following:

```
def _doc_mean(self, doc):
    doc_vector_values = []
    for w in doc:
        #print(w)
        if w.lower().strip() in self._E:
            Q = np.zeros((1, 200), dtype=np.float64)   #this is a zero array for when a word doesnt have a vector representation in our pretrained embeddings
            doc_vector_values.append(self._E.get(w, Q))

        with warnings.catch_warnings():
            warnings.simplefilter("ignore", category=RuntimeWarning)
    return np.mean(np.array(doc_vector_values, dtype=np.float64), axis=0)

def fit(self, X, y=None):
    return self

def transform(self, X):
    return np.array([self._doc_mean(doc) for doc in X])

def fit_transform(self, X, y=None):
    return self.fit(X).transform(X)
```

in _doc_mean, i compare w with the keys in a dictionary E_, if there is a match, then load the value of the key-value pair which contains a 1*200 vector into a list, if there is no match, then load numpy.zeros((1,200)) into a list. This list is now converted to an array and the mean calculated.

When i instantiate the class and fit-transform my 'doc' data

```
mc = MeanClass()        
X_ = mc.fit_transform(doc)
```

X_ is of dtype "object" and the places where there was a mismatch was replaced with nan instead of numpy.zero.

This leads to multiple other problems in my code that i cant fix. What am i doing wrong?

EDIT: 
The E_ dictionary looks like this :

```
{'hello': array([ 5.84850e-02,  6.20640e-02, ..... -2.08990e-02])
'good':  array([ -4.80050e-02,  2.80610e-02, ..... -5.04991e-02])
```

while doc looks like this :

```
['hello', 'bye', 'good']
['good', 'bye', 'night']
```

Comment: give a Test Case

Comment: not sure how to do this but I just  gave examples of how the data im working with looks like

Comment: Check  the values of `E_`.  They look like 1d arrays, maybe (200,), not (1,200).  I'd suggest looking at `doc_vector_values` before the `mean` step.  Make sure it can be made into a proper n-d numeric array.   You don't provide information for us to recreate your data.  That means you have to provide all the debugging info. There's a limit to how much code we can run in our heads.

Comment: @hpaulj `E_` is a dictionary containing key-value pairs. Each value is one array with 200 element, which should be (1, 200).  `doc_vector_values`  before the `mean` is a list containing (x, 200) arrays where x varies depending on the doc. I convert that to an numpy array and the shape is (x,200). After calculating the mean, the shape becomes (200,) and i dont know why or if thats correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't given a [mcve], I'll create something simple:

```
In [125]: E_ = {'foo':np.arange(5), 'bar':np.arange(1,6), 'baz':np.arange(5,10)}                             
In [126]: doc = ['foo','bar','sub','baz','foo']
```

Now do the dictionary lookup:

```
In [127]: alist = []                                                                                         
In [128]: for w in doc: 
     ...:     alist.append(E_.get(w,np.zeros((1,5),int))) 
     ...:                                                                                                    
In [129]: alist                                                                                              
Out[129]: 
[array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]),
 array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]),
 array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]),
 array([5, 6, 7, 8, 9]),
 array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])]
In [130]: np.array(alist)                                                                                    
Out[130]: 
array([array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]), array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]),
       array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]), array([5, 6, 7, 8, 9]),
       array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])], dtype=object)
```

The arrays in `E_` are all shape (5,).  The 'fill' array is (1,5).  Due to the mismatch in shapes, the `Out[130]` array is 1d object.

I think you are trying to avoid the 'fill' case, but you test `w.lower().strip() in self._E`, and then use `w` in the `get`.  So you might get the `Q` value sometimes.  I got it with the 'sub' string.

If instead I make the 'fill' be (5,):

```
In [131]: alist = []                                                                                         
In [132]: for w in doc: 
     ...:     alist.append(E_.get(w,np.zeros((5,),int))) 
     ...:                                                                                                    
In [133]: alist                                                                                              
Out[133]: 
[array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]),
 array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]),
 array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0]),
 array([5, 6, 7, 8, 9]),
 array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])]
In [134]: np.array(alist)                                                                                    
Out[134]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

The result is a (n,5) numeric array.

I can take two different means.  One is the mean across all words, with a value for each 'attribute'.  The other is the mean for each word, which I could just as well have gotten by taking the `mean` in `E_`.

```
In [135]: np.mean(_, axis=0)                                                                                 
Out[135]: array([1.2, 2. , 2.8, 3.6, 4.4])
In [137]: np.mean(__, axis=1)                                                                                
Out[137]: array([2., 3., 0., 7., 2.])   # mean for each 'word'
```

`mean` of the object array in `Out[130]`:

```
In [138]: np.mean(_130, axis=0)                                                                              
Out[138]: array([[1, 2, 2, 3, 4]])
```

The result is (1,5) and looks like `Out[135]` truncated, but I'd have to dig a bit further to be sure.

Hopefully this gives you an idea of what to watch out for.  And an idea of the kind of 'minimal reproducable concrete example' that we find most useful.

Comment: yes, thank you. I did the same in `In[127]` to `In[130]` and didn't get the zero array as you did. I now understand why my dtype is object. I also changed the shape of my fill to `(200, )` but my dtype didn't change, the shape didn't change and the nans are still in the X_. I dont know if its important to mention that my code runs with mutlple `mean of empty slice` warnings even though i tried to suppress it. Do you think that has any effect. I now know what an mrce is and would ask better questions in future. Thanks